# GDB loop_continue produces warning message

Tags: gdb

In order to practice `loop_continue`, I wrote the following user-defined GDB command:

```
#
# Print all odd numbers less than a given number.
#
define print_all_odds_less_than
    set $max = $arg0
    set $i   = 0

    while $i < ($max - 1)
        set $i = $i + 1

        if ($i % 2) == 0
            loop_continue
        end

        printf "Odd number %u is less than %u\n", $i, $max
    end

    printf "Done\n"
end
```

Sample run:

```
(gdb) print_all_odds_less_than 10
Odd number 1 is less than 10
Odd number 3 is less than 10
Odd number 5 is less than 10
Odd number 7 is less than 10
Odd number 9 is less than 10
Done
```

However, when I provide a value such that the `while` loop does not execute again after the *last* `loop_continue`, a **warning message** is produced and my user-defined command aborts execution.

```
(gdb) print_all_odds_less_than 9
Odd number 1 is less than 9
Odd number 3 is less than 9
Odd number 5 is less than 9
Odd number 7 is less than 9
warning: Error executing canned sequence of commands.
```

[Documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Command-Files.html#index-loop_005fcontinue) for `loop_continue`:

> This command skips the execution of the rest of the body of commands
> in the while loop in whose body it is included. Execution branches to
> the beginning of the while loop, where it evaluates the controlling
> expression.

From the documentation, I am unable to understand the mistake in my code.

My GDB version:

```
bash$ gdb --version
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5) 7.11.1
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: This looks like a gdb bug that you should maybe [report](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=gdb).

Comment: I think one possible fix is in `cli-script.c:execute_control_command_1` . There's code that looks at the type of the command that terminated a `while` loop. Right now, it alters the type if it was a `break` command. It should do the same if the command was `loop_continue`. (Actual code not included, to avoid diluting GPL-licensed code with CC).

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thank you so much! I tried your changes in a private GDB build and they work!

Comment: @ssbssa Thank you :) I have [reported](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=30083) the bug and mentioned the fix suggested by Mark.